# pgsql integer out of range for negative values

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, npgsql

It might sound an easy question to most of you. However, I'm unable to avoid this error. I have a table with id(primary_key) with bigint datatype and we started feeding records into  that from min -negative value (-9223372036854775808).

Now, I need to do some operation on that table based on each record data. So, I need to iterate through all records. This is the sample loop, I'm using and I'm getting below error with that:

```
    psql:update-migration2.sql:39: ERROR:  integer out of range
 CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at FOR with integer loop variable
```

Below , is the sample loop where I'm getting this error:

```
 do $$
declare
i bigint;
begin
for i in -9223372036854775808 ..  -9223372036852105062 loop
-- my logic
i := i + 1;
end loop;
end;$$
```

Any immediate help/solution will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOR ... LOOP only works on integer (-2147483648 to +2147483647)

This is OK:

```
do $$
declare
i bigint;
begin
for i in -2147483648 .. -2147483647  loop
-- my logic
end loop;
end;$$
DO
```

This fails:

```
do $$
declare
i bigint;
begin
for i in -2147483649 .. -2147483647  loop
-- my logic
end loop;
end;$$
ERROR:  integer out of range
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at FOR with integer loop variable
```